# first covering prefix in C++ - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, arrays

I just did a little codility test in C++... for the first covering prefix. As defined here,

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The first covering prefix of array A is the smallest integer P such that `0 ≤ P < N` and such that every value that occurs in array A also occurs in sequence `A[0], A[1], ..., A[P]`.

For example, the first covering prefix of the following 5−element array A:

```
A[0] = 2
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 1
A[3] = 0
A[4] = 1
```

is 3, because sequence `[ A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3] ]` equal to `[2, 2, 1, 0]`, contains all values that occur in array A.

Write a function

```
class Solution { public int ps(int[] A); }
```

that, given a zero-indexed non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the first covering prefix of A.

Assume that:

- N is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000];
- each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..N−1].

For example, given array A such that

```
A[0] = 2
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 1
A[3] = 0
A[4] = 1
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Complexity:

- expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
- expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

My solution was as follows (not saying it's optimal)... however, it only scored 48/100... Wondering if any of you can see the issue with the code that is causing incorrect answers?
Thanks

```
int ps ( int A[], int N )
{

long unique_array [N-1];
memset( unique_array, -1, N - 1 );
long value = 0, counter = 0, unique_num = 0, index = 0;

for ( counter; counter < N; counter++ )
{
    value = A[counter];

    if ( unique_array[value] < 0 )
    {
        unique_array[value] = value;
        unique_num ++;
    }
}

for ( counter = 0; counter < N; counter++ )
{
    value = A[counter];

    if ( unique_array[value] >= 0 )
    {
        unique_array[value] = -1;
        unique_num --;

        if ( unique_num == 0 )
            index = counter;
    }
}

return index;

}
```

Comment: ".. the smallest integer P such that 0≤P" - this is 0. Something seems wrong in your definition of "first covering prefix".

Comment: Actually my description was edited once I'd posted it... so my description not longer makes much sense. Sorry.

Comment: A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The first covering prefix of array A is the smallest integer P such that 0≤P<N and such that every value that occurs in array A also occurs in sequence A[0], A[1], ..., A[P].
For example, the first covering prefix of the following 5−element array A:
A[0] = 2  A[1] = 2  A[2] = 1
A[3] = 0  A[4] = 1
is 3, because sequence [ A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3] ] equal to [2, 2, 1, 0], contains all values that occur in array A.

Comment: Assume that:
N is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..N−1].

Comment: "Write a function `class Solution`" - so a function or a class? Since when does C have classes?

Comment: I assume that this is a homework, due to how the problem is written...

Comment: It's a demo test on Codility... NOT homework. Reason it says "class solution" is that you are also able to answer in Java or several other languages.

Answer (score 1):

The array `unique_array` should have length `N`, not `N-1`:

```
long unique_array[N]; // not N-1
```

In addition, `memset` will not set all elements of the array to `-1`; use a loop to do that:

```
for ( counter = 0; counter < N; counter++ )
{
    unique_array[counter] = -1;
}
```

Actually, you only need an array of bits, not of `long` values. You can initialize the array to 0, and set individual entries to 1 instead of `value`:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
if ( unique_array[value] == FALSE )
{
    unique_array[value] = TRUE;
    unique_num ++;
}
```

If you do this change, then you can initialize the array to 0 without an explicit loop:

```
int unique_array[N] = {0}; // this syntax only works with 0, not with -1
```

Comment: Thanks man. Why won't memset set all elements to -1 out of interest? If that's true then that might be the main issue.

Comment: `memset` sets the specified number of *bytes* to the specified value. So two mistakes here: number of bytes is `N` but should be `N * sizeof(long)`; and they might be set to a wrong value (usually "set all bytes to -1" is the same as "set the value to -1", but this is not guaranteed).

Comment: memset() was exactly the issue 100/100 now!!! Thanks again.